# Excel AverageIf function Criteria error

Tags: excel

I have a data source listing months from January-11 to December-14.  I'm trying to find the Average numeric data input for each of those months.  I'm using the AverageIf function with criteria of "January-11" and "February-11" and "March-11" up to "December-14".

**Problem:** the resulting data is showing me averages for the month of "February-11", but there is no corresponding data for "February-11" in my source data.  Why and how could the AverageIf function be showing me data for 'February-11' when there is not source data for 'February-11'.  Any ideas why?

Example:
Excel Formula bar `=AVERAGEIF($B$13:$B$14562,"February-11",$G$13:$G$14562)`
for example reasons, Column B is Month  Column G is GreenInv

I've tried changing the formulas to use wild cards...

```
=AVERAGEIF($C$24:$C$14562,"February???",$D$24:$D$14562)
```

still no good!

Stumped!
Appreciate help!

Workbook:

> `Month    RedInv  BlueInv    GreenInv     OrangeInv   BlackInv`
>
> `01/28/11   0       15        4               1062    0`
>
> `01/28/11   0        8        2               1051    0`
>
> `11/01/11   0     -699       6                  50    56`
>
> `11/20/11   0     -712       2                  21    26`
>
> `11/16/12   0        0       5                 439    439`
>
> `11/16/12   0        0       5                 439    439`
>
> `11/16/12   0        0       1                 435    438`

Comment: any chance to see your workbook?

Comment: I cannot post images...but here's what it looks like

Comment: At least seeing some sample data (that has the same problem) would help.  (In trying to post the data, you may even find your own mistake!)

Comment: can you upload your workbook using any fileuploader (e.g. https://dropbox.com)?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfc2fjtk628wpha/StackOverFlow%20Question.docx.xlsx

Comment: don't see any problem - your data don't have `February-11` and returns `#DIV/0!` for me as expected: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QfVor.png

Comment: btw, your formula is completle wrong. You're searching _string_ `"February-11"` in range `$C$24:$C$14562`, however your range contains _dates_ with number format `mmmm-yy`. You should use something like this: `=AVERAGEIFS($D$24:$D$14562;$C$24:$C$14562,"<"&DATE(2011,3,1),$C$24:$C$14562,">"&DATE(2011,1,31))`

Comment: Simoco, this worked.  Thank you!  =AVERAGEIFS($C$13:$C$402,$B$13:$B$402,">"&DATE(2011,3,1),$B$13:$B$402,"<"&DATE(2011,3,31))

Comment: @simoco - you should post an answer with that, so JH can accept.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, you're searching *string* "February-11" in range `$C$24:$C$14562`, however your range contains *dates* with number format `mmmm-yy`. 
You should use something like this instead:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($D$24:$D$14562,$C$24:$C$14562,"<"&DATE(2011,3,1),
                           $C$24:$C$14562,">"‌​&DATE(2011,1,31))
```